# How to copy merge files of two different directories with different extensions into one directory and remove the duplicated ones

Tags: python-3.x

I would need a Python function which performs below action:

I have two directories which in one of them I have files with .xml format and in the other one I have files with .pdf format. To simplify things consider this example:

**Directory 1:** ***a.xml***, ***b.xml***, ***c.xml***

**Directory 2:** ***a.pdf***, ***c.pdf***, ***d.pdf***

##### Output:

**Directory 3:** ***a.xml***, ***b.xml***, ***c.xml***, ***d.pdf***

As you can see the priority is with the xml files in the case that both extensions have similar names.

I would be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `shutil` module and the `os` module to achieve this. This function will work on the following assumption:

- A given directory has all files with the same extension
- The `priority_directory` will be the directory with file extensions to be prioritized
- The `secondary_directory` will be the directory with file extensions to be dropped in case of a name collision
  Try:

```py
import os,shutil

def copy_files(priority_directory,secondary_directory,destination = "new_directory"):
    file_names = [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in os.listdir(priority_directory)]    # get the file names to check for collisions
    os.mkdir(destination)    # make a new directory
    for file in os.listdir(priority_directory):    # this loop copies the first direcotory as it is
        file_path = os.path.join(priority_directory,file)
        dst_path = os.path.join(destination,file)
        shutil.copy(file_path,dst_path)
    for file in os.listdir(secondary_directory):    # this loop checks for collisions and drops files whose name collide
        if(os.path.splitext(file)[0] not in file_names):
            file_path = os.path.join(secondary_directory,file)
            dst_path = os.path.join(destination,file)
            shutil.copy(file_path,dst_path)
    print(os.listdir(destination))
```

##### Let's run it with your direcotry names as arguments:

```py
copy_files('directory_1','directory_2','directory_3')
```

You can now check a new directory with the name `directory_3` will be created with the desired files in it.

This will work for all such similar cases no matter what the extension is.

###### Note: There should not be a need to do this i guess cause a directory can have two files with the same name as long as the extensions differ.

Answer (score 1):

Rough working solution:

```
import os
from shutil import copy2

d1 = './d1/'
d2 = './d2/'
d3 = './d3/'

ext_1 = '.xml'
ext_2 = '.pdf'

def get_files(d: str, files: list):
    directory = os.fsencode(d)
    for file in os.listdir(d):
        dup = False
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename[-4:] == ext_2:
            for (x, y) in files:
                if y == filename[:-4] + ext_1:
                    dup = True
                    break
        if dup:
            continue
        files.append((d, filename))

files = []

get_files(d1, files)
get_files(d2, files)

for d, file in files:
    copy2(d+file, d3)
```

I'll see if I can get it to look/perform better.